# Why do I receive an error stating onAuth is not a Function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, refluxjs

I'm an app to fit the new firebase SDK. It compiles not problem but app will not display as I receive an error via console that stats onAuth is not a function

I've been through the upgrade process here: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web

Can't seem to get it to work

```
'use strict';

import Reflux from 'reflux';
import update from 'react-addons-update';
import Actions from '../actions/Actions';
require('firebase/auth');
require('firebase/database');
require('firebase/firestore');

var config = {
    apiKey: 'XXXXX',
    authDomain: 'XXXXXX',
    databaseURL: 'XXXXXX'
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

const baseRef =  firebase.database().ref();
const usersRef = baseRef.child('users');

const defaultUser = {
    uid: '',
    username: '',
    upvoted: null,
    submitted: null,
    isLoggedIn: false,
    md5hash: null,
    latestPost: null
};

let currentUser = Object.assign({}, defaultUser);

const UserStore = Reflux.createStore({

    listenables: Actions,

    init() {
        // triggered by auth changes
        baseRef.onAuth((authData) => {
            if (!authData) {
                // user is logged out
                usersRef.off();
                this.logoutCompleted();
            } else {
                // user is logged in
                this.loginCompleted(authData.uid);
            }
        });
    },

    logout() {
        baseRef.unauth();
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`baseRef` is a Reference type object:

```
const baseRef =  firebase.database().ref();
```

As you can see from the API documentation, [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference) doesn't have an method called `onAuth` or `unauth`.  Not sure what you're trying to do here, but it's obviously not following the documented API.

Comment: its deprecated. it used to work when you could call firebaseURL and onAuth was a working function

Comment: I'd go as far as to say it's not just deprecated, but completely removed.  You'll need to code an alternative using the provided APIs.